# Converting response to JSON format spring

Tags: spring, jackson

Hi I am struggling to solve this problem when I do a normal SELECT statement it returns a JSON response but when I do a SELECT COUNT statement it returns like this

[image]

I want it to be on JSON format too

```
@Repository
public interface FinanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Finance, Long>{
  List<Finance> findTop5ByOrderByRevenueDesc();
  List<Finance> findTop5ByOrderByProfitDesc();
  @Query(
        value = "SELECT currency, COUNT(currency) AS tally FROM finance "
                + "GROUP BY currency ORDER BY tally DESC LIMIT 5",
                nativeQuery=true)
  List<?> findByCurrency();
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/topCurrency")
  private List<?> getTopCurrency(){
  return financeRepository.findByCurrency();
}
```

This is what I did so far

```
public class CurrencyResponse {

@JsonProperty("Currency")
private List<?> currency;

public List<?> getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(List<?> currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
}
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/topCurrency")
private ResponseEntity<?> getTopCurrency(){
    CurrencyResponse response = new CurrencyResponse();
    response.setCurrency(financeRepository.findByCurrency());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and it returns this

```
Currency:[
     "USD",
     3,
     "EURO",
     2,
     "PESO",
     1
]
```

but I want it to be like this

```
{
     "USD":3,
     "EURO":2,
     "PESO":1
}
```

I already have the jackson dependency on my POM, thanks in advance

Comment: Create a Custom Pojo Class with the following fields and use List<CustomClass> in @Repository.

Comment: I already did that actually but unfortunately it did not work as intended

Comment: the result is like this
Currency:[
     "USD",
     3
]

Comment: I'd like it to be like this {["Currency": "USD", "Talley":3]}

Comment: I hace edited it thanks

Comment: just like Finance create a pojo in List<pojoclass> findByCurrency();

Comment: I created a POJO already but the result is not what I wanted it to be the result is like this {
     "Currency":[
      "USD",
       3,
       "EURO",
       2,
       "PESO",
      1
]
}    But I want it to be like this: {"USD":3,"EURO":2,"PESO":1}

Comment: could you post that pojo also for reference

Comment: The POJO is already posted it's the class named CurrencyResponse

Comment: List will always be converted to array as you mention and its valid JSON. It you still want to change the response you mentioned the  return a Map of string, long. Convert your currency object to map entities and Json output will be as per your desired one

Comment: @Sandeep It returns an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by changing

```
List<?> findByCurrency();
```

into

```
List<Object[]> findByCurrency();
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/topCurrency")
private ResponseEntity<List<Object>> getTopCurrency(){
    List<Object[]> results = financeRepository.findByCurrency();
    List<Object> currencyList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(Object[] object : results) {
        Map<Object, Object> currencies = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        currencies.put("Currency", object[0]);
        currencies.put("Tally", object[1]);
        
        currencyList.add(currencies);
   }
   return new ResponseEntity<>(currencyList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

since the value that the query returns is like a 2d array I used List<Object[]> instead of List< Object> and I manually put the results into JSON format by using Map

Answer (score 0):

You should include Jackson dependency with the following, in your pom.xml file
...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

...
..then in your controller should have the following
...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/topCurrency")
```

...
finally ResponseEntity model should look like this, try writing a similar utility class for mapping , you should see the resulting right format
...

```
 List<JSONObject> entities = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (Entity n : entityList) {
            JSONObject entity = new JSONObject();
            entity.put("aa", "bb");
            entities.add(entity);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

...

Comment: I already ave jackson dependecy on my POM and my controller is already on @RestController